# Rails Unicorns and Postgres Temp tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, unicorn

We have a pretty typical setup for our Rails app here at work:
Nginx
Rails
Unicorn (5 workers)
Postgres

There is a part of the app that is creating a temp table, populating it with data and then reading.  The other developers are concerned that two unicorns might try to access the temp table at the same time on the same connection due to ActiveRecord connection pooling.  Is this an issue?  Do I need to uniquely name my temp table per unicorn worker or will each unicorn have its own database session with its own Temp table.